# SSRS get old scheduled report files

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using daily SSRS reports to send email as Excel.
Now i lost my some data from server. I don't have backup of Database. I can't get files from email which was send to client.
Is there any way that i can receive the file which emailed from SSRS?

Comment: You weren't using snapshots or cached reports for your subscriptions by any change, were you?

Comment: no i am not using that.

Comment: Perhaps, you should ask the people who manage your email server if they can help. Then, ask your DBA why there is no backup of the database, you know, just to make sure they are competent. Did you happen to CC, or BCC, another email on the report subscription?

Comment: Though you don't have a backup i find it hard to believe the org doesn't have a backup. If that is the case then the exchange server (old emails) would likely be your best bet to get some of the old subscriptions.